# Upload photo and video together with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to upload photos and videos together.

I am using the [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

my mvc controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ContentResult Add(List<HttpPostedFileBase> file, VideoViewModel item)
    {
        return Content(_output.ConvertToJson(), "application/json");
    }
```

my javascript codes :

```
 $scope.item = {
                Address: '',
                Name: ''
            };
            $scope.files = [];
            $scope.file = null;
            $scope.video = null;
            $scope.response = {};
            $scope.confirmAdd = function () {
                if ($scope.add_form.$valid) {
                    $scope.files[0] = $scope.file;
                    $scope.files[1] = $scope.video;
                    $upload.upload({
                url: 'User/Add',
                method: 'POST',
                data: $scope.item,
                file: $scope.files,
            }) .progress(function (evt) {
                        $scope.percent = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.response = data;
                    }).error(function (err) {
                        $scope.percent = 0;
                    });

                } else {
                    $scope.add_form.submitted = true;
                }
            }
            $scope.onFileSelect = function ($files) {
                $scope.file = $files[0];
            };
            $scope.onVideoSelect = function ($files) {
                $scope.video = $files[0];
            };
```

error :

IIS 8.0 Detailed Error - 404.13 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length
Most likely causes:
Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request because the content length exceeds the configured value

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: May be related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded

Comment: @ Bradley Braithwaite. thanks a lot.